# The await expression can only be used in an async function. Although there is async in this function in Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have an asynchronous function for checking internet access which is in another file. Here is its code:

```dart
//Check User Connection
class CheckUserConnection {

  Future checkInternetAvailability() async {
    try {
      final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('example.com');
      if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
        return true;
      }
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

I need it to be activated when a button is pressed in the main menu. Here is the code for this screen:

```dart
void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Example';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
        home: Container(
            child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        // body: const MyStatelessWidget(),
              body: const MainWidget(),
      ),
    )
    );
  }
}

// class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
//   const MyStatelessWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
class MainWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MainWidget> createState() => _MainWidgetState();
}

class _MainWidgetState extends State<MainWidget> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    InternetDialogHandler _internetDialogHandler = InternetDialogHandler();
    CheckUserConnection _checkUserConnection = CheckUserConnection();
    bool _internetAvailable = await _checkUserConnection.checkInternetAvailability();
    // bool _internetAvailable = false;
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            children: [
              GradientButton(label: 'New Game', onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const NewGameRoute()),
                );
              }),
              GradientButton(label: 'Continue Game', onTap: () {
                if(_internetAvailable)
                {
                  //do something here;
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const NewGameRoute()),
                  );
                } else{
                  //handle no internet here
                  _internetDialogHandler.showInternetDialog(context);
                }



              }),
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              GradientButton(label: 'Back Button', onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const BackRoute()),
                );



                // print('Button 1');



              }),
              GradientButton(label: 'Button 2', onTap: () {print('Button 2');}),
              GradientButton(label: 'Internet', onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const InternetRoute()),
                );
              }),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But the problem is that when I paste:

```dart
bool _internetAvailable = await _checkUserConnection.checkInternetAvailability();
```

I get an error:

```dart
The await expression can only be used in an async function.
```

Why? Async is already in that function, which is in another file. Where else do I need to add async in my main page code?

I've been given advice:

```dart
In initstate just call a method. And in that method add async and check internrt and set state based on internet availability
```

But since I'm a beginner, I don't understand what exactly I should do.

**Edit1.** This code does not throw any errors:

```dart
void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Example';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
        home: Container(
            child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        // body: const MyStatelessWidget(),
              body: const MainWidget(),
      ),
    )
    );
  }
}

// class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
//   const MyStatelessWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
class MainWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MainWidget> createState() => _MainWidgetState();
}



class _MainWidgetState extends State<MainWidget> {
  CheckUserConnection _checkUserConnection = CheckUserConnection();
  bool? _internetAvailable;

  void checkNet() async{
    _internetAvailable = await
    _checkUserConnection.checkInternetAvailability();

    // can you do any async operation into this method, Just be careful to check it
  }

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    checkNet();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    InternetDialogHandler _internetDialogHandler = InternetDialogHandler();
    // CheckUserConnection _checkUserConnection = CheckUserConnection();
    // bool _internetAvailable = await _checkUserConnection.checkInternetAvailability();
    // bool _internetAvailable = false;
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            children: [
              GradientButton(label: 'New Game', onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const NewGameRoute()),
                );
              }),
              GradientButton(label: 'Continue Game', onTap: () {
                // if(_internetAvailable)
                // {
                //   //do something here;
                //   Navigator.push(
                //     context,
                //     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const NewGameRoute()),
                //   );
                // } else{
                //   //handle no internet here
                //   _internetDialogHandler.showInternetDialog(context);
                // }
                return _internetAvailable == null?
                _internetDialogHandler.showInternetDialog(context)
                    :
                print('_internetAvailable = null');
              }),
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              GradientButton(label: 'Back Button', onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const BackRoute()),
                );



                // print('Button 1');



              }),
              GradientButton(label: 'Button 2', onTap: () {print('Button 2');}),
              GradientButton(label: 'Internet', onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const InternetRoute()),
                );
              }),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But the problem is that `_internetAvailable` returns `null` regardless of the Internet connection.

**Edi2.** Trying Kaushik Chandru's code:

```dart
  class _MainWidgetState extends State<MainWidget> {

  InternetDialogHandler _internetDialogHandler = InternetDialogHandler();
  CheckUserConnection _checkUserConnection = CheckUserConnection();

  @override
  void initState(){
  super.initState();

  checkInternet((){
    //Add what to do if internet is available

    Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const NewGameRoute()),
          );
  },
          (){
        //Add what to do if no internet
            _internetDialogHandler.showInternetDialog(context);
      }
  );
  }

  checkInternet(Function? ifAvailable, Function? ifUnavailable) async{
    bool internetAvailable = await _checkUserConnection.checkInternetAvailability();
    if(internetAvailable)
    {
      ifAvailable();
    }
    else{
      ifUnavailable();
    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
...
```

I have this error:

```dart
88:18: Error: Can't use an expression of type 'Function?' as a function because it's potentially null.
 - 'Function' is from 'dart:core'.
Try calling using ?.call instead.
      ifAvailable();
                 ^
lib/main.dart:91:20: Error: Can't use an expression of type 'Function?' as a function because it's potentially null.
 - 'Function' is from 'dart:core'.
Try calling using ?.call instead.
      ifUnavailable();
                   ^
```

**Edit3.** For Kaushik Chandru only

```dart
lib/main.dart:92:21: Error: Expected an identifier, but got ';'.
Try inserting an identifier before ';'.
      ifAvailable()?;
                    ^
lib/main.dart:92:21: Error: Expected ':' before this.
      ifAvailable()?;
                    ^
lib/main.dart:95:23: Error: Expected an identifier, but got ';'.
Try inserting an identifier before ';'.
      ifUnavailable()?;
                      ^
lib/main.dart:95:23: Error: Expected ':' before this.
      ifUnavailable()?;
                      ^
lib/main.dart:92:18: Error: Can't use an expression of type 'Function?' as a function because it's potentially null.
 - 'Function' is from 'dart:core'.
Try calling using ?.call instead.
      ifAvailable()?;
                 ^
lib/main.dart:95:20: Error: Can't use an expression of type 'Function?' as a function because it's potentially null.
 - 'Function' is from 'dart:core'.
Try calling using ?.call instead.
      ifUnavailable()?;
                   ^
```

**Edit4 for Hossein Asadi.** Just in case, I added the print in different places, tried different options. But there is no such entry in the console. When I click on my button, the condition that _internetAvailable == null is triggered.

```dart
class _MainWidgetState extends State<MainWidget> {
  CheckUserConnection _checkUserConnection = CheckUserConnection();
  bool? _internetAvailable;

  void checkNet() async{
    _internetAvailable = await
    _checkUserConnection.checkInternetAvailability();
    print("ok");
    setState((){});

    // can you do any async operation into this method, Just be careful to check it
  }

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    checkNet();
    print("ok");
  }
```

Comment: try to replace this `Future checkInternetAvailability() async` with this `async FutureCheckInternetAvailability() `.

[see some async examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Comment: No, it doesn't work, unfortunately. This causes other errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you called `bool _internetAvailable = await _checkUserConnection.checkInternetAvailability();` in build method, In the event that build method can't be `async`.

you must be do like below code:

```
class _MainWidgetState extends State<MainWidget> {
   bool? _internetAvailable;

   void checkNet() async{
   _internetAvailable = await 
   _checkUserConnection.checkInternetAvailability();

setState((){});
  
   // can you do any async operation into this method, Just be careful to check it
   }

  @overrider
  void initState(){
   super.initState();
   checkNet();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ....
    return _internetAvailable == null?
    CupertinoActivityIndicator()//loading
    :Center(
      child: Column(
    ....
```

Comment: Thank you. But I'm not sure if it works the way it should. _internetAvailable always returns null. When I turn the Internet on or off, the result is the same. What could be the reason?

Comment: My answer edited

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing has changed after the addition of setState((){});. Still null. What could be the reason?

Comment: With add print("ok") into checkNet method after await into setState, check Does it work and print?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. My edited code i in Edit4.

Comment: Can you hot restart project and check again?

Comment: Yes. I had done this several times. But the hot restart didn't work for some reason. I was so tired that I turned off the PC. When I entered the program the next time, everything began to work. I don’t know why, but in this particular case, I need not a hot restart, but a complete stop and start of main.dart. So everything works. Thank you.

Comment: Cool, your welcome ✌️

Answer (score 2):

Add an initstate to the stateful widget. Inside the initstate add this code

```dart
checkInternet((){
 //Add what to do if internet is available
}, 
  (){
  //Add what to do if no internet
  }
);
```

Then define a function

```
checkInternet(VoidCallback ifAvailable, VoidCallback ifUnavailable) async{
bool internetAvaibale = await _checkInternetConnection.checkInternetAvailability();
if(internetAvailable)
{
  ifAvailable();
}
else{
  ifUnavailable();
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need this condition to be different for different buttons. For example, when clicking on Continue Game and the Internet connection is available, my user should be taken to Continue Game. If it's a New Game, then a New Game, and so on. How to do it?

Comment: I have edited Edit2 to show the error I am getting. What could be the reason?

Comment: Adding ? causes the following errors (Edit3)

Comment: Sorry my bad. I had added ? At the wrong place. Edited again

Comment: Unfortunately, it still throws errors. I also edited my Edit3.

Comment: Edited the answer again. It will work now

Comment: Yes, now it works. Thank you. It's rather strange, but when I make an APK file and run it in another emulator, my application thinks that this device does not have Internet access. But that is definitely a question for another topic.

Comment: this is the better answer.